# the + adjective + of + something

Tags: construction

I've came across *the sizzling of [something]* and I've  found out *sizzling* is an adjective. However, I can't understand the construction *the [adj] of [sth]*. All I know is the construction *the [adj]* as in *the rich* (meaning *rich people*).

This is the context of a description of a kitchen.

> There’s **the sizzling of** a frying pan, chairs being scraped back, metal chopsticks clinking against bowls as someone sets the table. Probably Sarah. It sounds like everyone is in the kitchen.

Comment: There’s **the sizzling of a frying pan**= **hissing sound of a frying pan**

Comment: It is really helpful... ! Thank you so much

Comment: "Sizzling" qualifies as a noun by virtue of the presence of the determiner "the" and by the _of_ PP as its complement. Adjectives don't take determiners or PP complements.

Comment: @BillJ Oh ! I got it :)))) if so, the noun 'sizzling' is a gerund from the intransitive verb 'sizzle'?

Comment: As Kate Bunting says, "Sizzling" **can** be an adjective, but your sentence uses the present participle of the verb "sizzle" as a **noun**. Doing that is very common in English, and very useful! For example, "She shouts"..."I hear shouting". You might find [this](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/what-type-of-noun-is-made-from-the-ing-form-of-a-verb) helpful.

Comment: I've read what you posted ! It helps a lot !!!! thank you 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sizzling* is an adjective in a sentence like

> I picked up the sizzling frying pan.

However, the passage you quote is a description of the sounds coming from the kitchen. Here, *sizzling* is a noun; the name of the sound that the hot pan makes.

Comment: Wow,,,,,,,,,,, It seems like I got an e-mail from my English teacher.. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I think the sizzling of a frying pan is fine as it is the noise produced overall by the stuff being fried in it.

Comment: @Lambie - Why do you think I said there was anything wrong with it? I merely pointed out that it isn't an adjective as the OP thought.

Comment: Yes, it can be an adjective, sure, but here it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelism:

There is the sizzling of a frying pan, the scraping back of a chair, the clinking of metal chopsticks against bowls as someone is setting the table.

Now, it's parallel but slightly over the top. The historic present is used here.

ing added to verbs make them gerunds, *some people say gerund nouns*.  However, it is common in English to get this structure:

- the barking of dogs in the street
- the cawing of crows in the treet.

Now, many of these gerunds can be used also as adjectives:

The barking dogs
The cawing crows
The clinking chopsticks